# How to publish Android API on Google Play?

Tags: android, api, google-play, publish

I have recently developed an API which can be used in Android applications. Could someone please let me know how I can make it available on Google Play? As far as I know, we can only upload apk's on Google Play and am not sure how to make api available.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> Could someone please let me know how I can make it available on Google Play?

You can't. The Play Store is for apps, not programming libraries, and I assume that your "API" is in the form of a JAR or an Android library project.

> As far as I know, we can only upload apk's on Google Play

Correct.

Answer (score -1):

The category tools in Apps is your best bet. Thought I would suggest actually promoting it yourself on a dev forum such as xda-developers or such. As you may not see much tracking otherwise.